# Is there something in Sitecore 8.2 that breaks bundling?

Tags: bundling

I just upgraded our Sitecore **8.1** Update 2 install to Sitecore **8.2** Update 1.

Our solution has utilized MVC bundling since we implemented it a year ago.

But now -- after the upgrade -- bundling no longer works correctly.

- The following Nuget packages are installed:

  - Antlr 3.5.0.2
  - Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.2-beta1
  - Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0
  - Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.1.3
  - WebGrease 1.6.0
- The namespaces in my Global.asax and Global.asax.cs match.
- In the head of my layout I have: `@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")`
- In my *App_Start/BundleConfig.cs* I have:

---

```cs
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
    "~/assets/css/bootstrap.css",
    "~/assets/css/bootstrap-select.css",
    "~/assets/css/font-awesome.css",
    "~/assets/css/slick.css",
    "~/assets/css/app.css",
    "~/assets/css/back-to-top.css"
));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include(
    "~/assets/js/navigation.js",
    "~/assets/js/bootstrap.js",
    "~/assets/js/bootstrap-select.js",
    "~/assets/js/handlebars.js",
    "~/assets/js/moment-with-locales.js",
    "~/assets/js/lodash.js",
    "~/assets/js/slick.js",
    "~/assets/js/jquery.browser.js",
    "~/assets/js/jquery.onmutate.js",
    "~/assets/js/js.cookie.js",
    "~/assets/js/main.js",
    "~/assets/js/jquery.validate*",
    "~/assets/js/marketo.js",
    "~/assets/js/back-to-top.js"
));
```

If I view source I see.

There is no ?v=somerandomstring like one would normally see.

The same thing occurs on my JS bundle.

If I add `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;` to the end BundleConfig.cs file it has zero effect.   The same link gets written into the HTML.

This is driving me nuts.   Did something in 8.2 break bundling?

---

UPDATE:

Removing the following from the Global.asax.cs file breaks the site:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Context.Items["Disable"] = new VersionCountDisabler();
}
```

My guess is that it is expected code and that my patch is not working / in the right place:

```
<httpRequestBegin>
    <processor type="MySite.Presentation.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin, MySite.Presentation" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
</httpRequestBegin>
```

Comment: Global.asax is private in 8.2. You will need to move your global.asax code to an initialization pipeline.

Comment: So, I can no longer have my own Global.asax.cs that inherits from Application?   How do I go about moving the the code to the intialization pipeline.   See my update above so you can see my current Global.asax.cs

Comment: Yup. Gone. I guess Sitecore wanted to force people into pipelines and out of the Global.asax. Just move you code the example I made below and change the config to your namespace. Its the exact same thing.

Comment: Only thing, is I don't see one for Application_PreSendRequestHeader on the laubplusco.net site.   :-(

Comment: Let me look around for that

Comment: It looks like the http request pipeline has the response object. We can bind your appendheader to that. http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/replace-content/

Comment: Add it in web.config: `<httpProtocol><customHeaders><add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" /></customHeaders></httpProtocol>`

Comment: FYI: I believe the methods being marked as private/internal has been reported as a bug by Sitecore.

Comment: I believe the code updates below will do what you need it to do and use Jammy's web.config change.

Comment: The best way to do this is via initialize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global.asax is private in 8.2. You will need to move your global.asax code to an initialization pipeline. Thats why your app_start code isn't running.

```
namespace YourApp
{
    public class Initialize
    {
        public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            // app start here
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            if (!Tracker.IsActive)
            {
                Tracker.StartTracking();
            }
        }
    }

    public class VersionCount : HttpRequestProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {
            args.Context.Items["Disable"] = new VersionCountDisabler();
        }
    }
}
```

Then your config

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="YourApp.Pipelines.Initialize.YourAppStart, YourApp"
                  patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>



<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <httpRequestBegin>
        <processor type="YourApp.Pipelines.Initialize.VersionCount, YourApp"
                    patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </httpRequestBegin>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Other Global.asax functions https://laubplusco.net/global-asax-sitecore-pipelines/

Comment: Ok, so implemented and now I get a bunch of lovely "Object reference not set" errors on some of my modules that I did not get before.   It is like the population of models is getting interrupted?

Comment: Can you give some details on the modules? Using Sitecore models or normal POCO models?

Comment: Sitecore model.  `Model.IsValid()` is true, but `Model.ShowDynamicContent()`  (which is a public bool exposed in the model) throws the Object reference not set).  :-(

Comment: remove the httpRequestBegin pipeline config and test again. We may have it in the wrong order.

Comment: Tried that no change, tried removing the initialize one too, no change.   So not sure what happened.   It was loading before just with no styles or scripts.

Comment: Any accidental configs make it into the site during testing?

Comment: I will get back into it on Monday

Comment: Ok, figured out at least what is breaking it.

Comment: I patched the httpRequestBegin one in before Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.CheckIgnoreFlag and that fixed the issue.