# How to set up Asset Bundling

Tags: bundling

I am trying to bundle assets. I read [Is there something in Sitecore 8.2 that breaks bundling?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3434/is-there-something-in-sitecore-8-2-that-breaks-bundling) which was the simplest example I could find. My RegisterBundles.Void() method is not being hit and minified bundles are not being created. We are running Sitecore 9.0.2

In my config:

```
<initialize>
    <processor type="MySite.Project.MySite.Pipelines.RegisterBundles, MySite.Project.MySite" />
</initialize>
```

In My Register Class I tested both single file and wildcard:

```
public class RegisterBundles : Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes
{        
    public override void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        Register(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    private void Register(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Assets/min/js").Include("~/Assets/js/*.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Assets/min/test").Include("~/Assets/js/mysite.global.js"));
    }
}
```

In My Layout/View:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Assets/min/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Assets/min/test")
```

When I do a show config my element is the last one added to the initialize element.

When I do a view source the script tag is rendering correctly but my process method is never hit so the assets are never registered. Do I need to patch instead or patch after or something in my config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess was correct.

You were missing `patch:before` statement.

Your config should look like this:

```
<initialize>
    <processor 
          type="MySite.Project.MySite.Pipelines.RegisterBundles, MySite.Project.MySite" 
          patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
</initialize>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter I added some logging and can see the process method is now hit. However the js is not being bundled into the min folder. I tried adding BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true to the Register method but didn't seem to make a difference. any ideas

Comment: Minification is another topic. You should have another processor but this time in `<preprocessRequest>` to enable optimizations. Take a look in this answer https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/14102/2056 for further details

Comment: Cheers. I've been thrown into a project as a full stack dev when I have minimal knowledge of frontend. I'll post another question if I can't work out the preprocessor.